# How to resolve a relative path, relative to any directory

Tags: python, pathlib

I'm aware of how to resolve a relative path like `'..\input\file\hello.txt'` to an absolute path, relative to the current working directory:

```
from pathlib import Path

rel_path = Path(r'..\input\file\hello.txt')
print(f'Absolute path: {rel_path.absolute()}'
```

Output when `cwd` is `C:\project\source\`:

```
C:\project\source\..\input\file\hello.txt
```

And I also known to use `.resolve()` to fully resolve indirections:

```
from pathlib import Path

rel_path = Path(r'..\input\file\hello.txt')
print(f'Resolved path: {rel_path.resolve()}'
```

Output when `cwd` is `C:\project\source\`:

```
C:\project\input\file\hello.txt
```

How can I resolve a path relative to any path without changing the current working directory (if at all)? And even when I must change the current working directory, how can I fully resolve a path that doesn't actually exist? (since `.resolve()` only works for existing objects)

For example, using the imaginary `get_relative_to()`:

```
get_relative_to(r'..\input\file\hello.txt', r'X:\bogus\folder')
```

Would ideally return `'X:\bogus\input\file\hello.txt'`

Comment: A partial solution appears to be `Path(r'X:\bogus\folder') / Path(r'..\input\file\hello.txt')` but that leaves the indirection in - if anyone knows...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from version 3.6 [resolve](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.resolve) has an argument `strict`, when `strict=False` the path can be resolved even if it doesn't exist. Example tested in 3.8.0:

```
from pathlib import Path


def get_relative_to(path1, path2):
    return (path2 / path1).resolve(strict=False)


print(
    get_relative_to(
        Path(r'..\input\file\hello.txt'),
        Path(r'X:\bogus\folder'),
    )
)

# X:\bogus\input\file\hello.txt
```

Comment: This is really close, I'll accept it. One issue I still found with it was that my system happens to have a drive letter assignment that's for a drive that's no longer connected - as a result, when trying to resolve a path starting with that drive letter (even when using `strict`) the call fails with `PermissionError: [WinError 21] The device is not ready` - so, apparently Python still tries to access the drive. It works for any other assigned drive letter or unassigned ones, so the answer is close enough.

Comment: @Grismar it is interesting that Python tries to check if the drive exists and fails here. I think the implementation can catch this PermissionError and treat it like the drive doesn't exist. Maybe worth opening a bug issue?

Comment: I was considering that, but before I do, I'm trying to find out exactly what the technical situation is on that system, because I've been unable to reproduce it on other systems. It's consistently occurring on that system though, so I'll try tracing the call into the library source and see if I can identify where it's tripping up.